# How to apply style to a Django form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

It is possible to change the style of form in the view?

I found in documentation this code:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.subject.errors }}
        <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
        {{ form.subject }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.message.errors }}
        <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
        {{ form.message }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.sender.errors }}
        <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
        {{ form.sender }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
        <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
       {{ form.cc_myself }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

But it just put a ugly input. I want to apply a class, or a css in this input. Is it possible?

This is my form:

```
class LoginView(NextUrlMixin, RequestFormAttachMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    default_next = '/'


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: are you use a framework css?? or custom style css ?

Comment: I buy a custom template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are use a custom css set the class CSS on the forms example:

```
email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
email.widget.attrs.update({'class':'customClass', 'required':'required'})
```

in this case set a customClass if you are using Bootstrap maybe you can use someone like this:

```
email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
email.widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'required':'required'})
```

this code is on your forms.pyp .. good luck
don't forget load your css file on your template

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by applying some attributes to the widget that you use:
more info can be found here [Official Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget)

for instance:

```
email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'class_value','placeholder':"Email here"}))
```

If you want to have the full control of the `form html` by keeping the same behavior as the one generated by django, the following will work

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" value="{{form.email.value}}" class='class_name' attrs='attrs' >

{{ form.email.errors}}  <!-- track errors for this field -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can attach a css file to your form (place a `{{ form.media }}` in your template) with this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('login-form-layout.css',)
        }
        js = (
            'https://some-cdn.com/some-framework.js'
            'login-form-script.js', 
        )
```

Inputs have an ID like `id_fiedname` so `login-form-layout.css` can be something like:

```
#id_email, #id_password {
    width: 200px;
}
```

You can do a lot with CSS and with javascript there are endless possibilities.

You may want to check ["Customizing widget instances"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) at the official Django documentation. For example, you can attach arbitrary attributes to the input tag using the attrs argument:

```
email = forms.EmailField(
    label='Email',  
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs{
        'class': 'my-super-special-input', 
        'placeholder': "mailbox@example.com"
    }),
)
```

There are other possibilities there, so check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django widget_tweaks. It’s real convenient. And you can easily change any attribute you want.

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% render_field form.field class=“your-class” %}
```